# Como criar projeto Web Asp.Net MVC no Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-azure

Sim, já vasculhei o [google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=criar%20webservice%20no%20azure), acessei [fóruns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911386/hosting-web-application-on-windows-azure) e assisti [vídeos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=web%20application%20on%20azure), mas infelizmente ainda não consegui um tutorial fácil de compreender para criar um projeto Web em Asp.Net MVC no Azure. O melhor tutorial que consegui foi [esse](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/), e [esse outro também](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/) .

Tenho dificuldades com o inglês, e por isso estou aqui no stackoverflow em português.
Estou seguindo todos os passos da maneira correta, mas o erro abaixo é exibido:

> Creating Microsoft Azure Web App
>
> Creation of Microsoft Azure Web App failed. Deployment failed for
>   /subscriptions/3e2ff127-654a-431f-a319-d8a7b4722759/resourceGroups/horariofacilweb/deployments/website_deployment
>
> Error in /subscriptions/3e2ff127-654a-431f-a319-d8a7b4722759/resourcegroups/horariofacilweb/providers/microsoft.insights/components/horariofacil2015:
>   The component already existed in a different resource group.

Alguém pode me socorrer?

Comment: Onde ocorrem os erros? No seu lugar, apagaria o Web Site na Azure e começaria de novo.

Comment: Os erros acontecem ao finalizar a criação do projeto, após carregar todos os módulos o erro é apresentado. Bem já apaguei e comecei de novo umas 7 vezes, sem exagero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, não sei se isso poderá ajudar alguém, mas ao invés de seguir os tutoriais, criei o projeto local sem o Azure e depois publiquei no mesmo. Está funcionando por enquanto, agora basta estudar sobre a conexão com o banco de dados do Azure.

Comment: Não tem muito segredo mesmo. Aliás, a alternativa de publicar por dentro do Visual Studio está muito estável agora. +1.